# GET AJAX query string parameters in Theme template - Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

There is a callback function that includes a js and then returns a theme.
The js included in turn makes an AJAX request to another callback function with some query string parameters.

Here is the code snippet:
Page requested: http://example.com/abc

```
function abc()
{
  drupal_add_js('sign-in.js');
  return theme('mypage');
}

//sign-in.js

ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/xyz",
    data: 'channels='+noofchannels',
    ....
});
```

I want to get this 'channels' parameter value in `mypage.tpl.php` theme file . Is this possible and how it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Since the AJAX call out to /xyz happens after the /abc page loading is complete, I don't think this is possible...

Typically, the 'success' function after the AJAX call would modify something on your page, i.e. take the 'channels' value and print it out somewhere.

But since the value of 'channels' is already known in your example (from the var 'noofchannels'), you could use JS to put it somewhere on your page before your AJAX call.

Why do you need the value of 'channels' inside your mypage.tpl.php file?